# TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normed'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, histogram

I am using `numpy.histogram` and I am getting this error:

```
import numpy as np
np.histogram(np.arange(4), bins=np.arange(5), normed=True)

TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normed'
```

I was expecting:

```
(array([0.2,0.25,0.25]),array([0,1,2,3,4]))
```

I am using numpy 1.24.3

Comment: The error is clear: histogram doesn't have "normed" parameters. See the docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: It was present in https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: And it was "Deprecated since version 1.6.0." - so they finally removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normed parameter in the numpy.histogram function was deprecated in NumPy version 1.21.0 and removed in version 1.24.0.

Example

```
import numpy as np

result = np.histogram(a=np.arange(4), bins=np.arange(5), density=True)
print(result)
# (array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 2):

*The normed keyword argument has been removed from np.histogram, np.histogram2d, and np.histogramdd. Use density instead. If normed was passed by position, density is now used.*

It is removed in `numpy 1.24.0`

They also say that normed is **equivalent to the density argument**, but produces incorrect results for unequal bin widths. It should not be used.

Link to doc: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.24.0-notes.html